# Returning custom messages in SqlAlchemy @validates decorator

Tags: python, json, exception, sqlalchemy

I'm relatively new to SQLAlchemy.

I've a very simple `model` with a custom `@validates` function using the sqlalchemy decorator:

```
class User(db.Model):
  ...
  email = db.Column(db.String(255)) # don't worry about uniqueness for now

  @validates('email')
  def validate_email(self, key, address):
    assert '@' in address # of course a regex is better, I know
    return address
```

and then later:

```
try:
  user = User('fidel#cuba.cu')
  db.session.add(user)
  db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
  print e.message # returns an empty string ''
```

what I'd like to do:

```
...
except Exception as e:
  # json_error is a custom function of my own 
  return json_error(e.message, 400)
```

So the question is:
How do I attach a custom error message to a custom validation rule in SQLAlchemy?
Maybe I need to create a custom Exception with the message in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assertions can take a second argument - the message to use if the assertion fails:

```
class User(db.Model):
  # ... snip ...

  @validates('email')
  def validate_email(self, key, address):
    assert '@' in address, "Invalid email"
    return address
```